# "Because you have more money than sense"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality

I saw an advertising poster on a Samsung shop that was saying "iPhone 5, because you have more money than sense".

But I don't get it, is that even a correct sentence?

Comment: Samsung is a top competitor against Apple (maker of the iPhone). The ad implies that iPhones are expensive but a poor product choice. Someone who buys one has more money than [*sense*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sense) ("sound mental capacity and understanding typically marked by shrewdness and practicality"). As an ad, it doesn't need to be a grammatical complete sentence.

Comment: but is it a grammatically correct sentence too?

Comment: It's not a sentence, it's an [**Advertising slogan**](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Advertising_slogans), which need be no more than a phrase.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically correct, but it is a phrase, not a sentence. It is saying that you have more money than you have sense (which as Zairja said in the above comments, "sound mental capacity and understanding typically marked by shrewdness and practicality", couldn't have put it better myself).

An important thing to note about this is that there is a difference between something being grammatically correct, and being a complete sentence. It is merely a subordinate clause, but a grammatically correct one. In the case of advertisement, this is commonly done. The part that's "missing" for it to be a complete sentence is an implied "buy the iPhone 5", or even "you would buy the iPhone 5".

> (You would buy the iPhone 5) because you have more money than sense.

Comment: I think the full sentence is something like "(Our competitor thinks you will buy its product) because you have more money than sense."

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't get it, is that even a correct sentence?

No, it's a sentence fragment.  It's short for something like "You should buy an iPhone 5, because you have more money than sense."